# How to map an array of objects stored in Redux inside the render() using ES6

Tags: react-native

New to RN and trying to understand object mapping. I can't seem to get the StackO answers similar to this to work in my app. I'd get this.props.locations was undefined, so I initialized the object with the object 'latlons' you see in the data structure below.

this.props.locations

```
{
  "latlons": {
    "latitude": "0",
    "longitude": "0",
    "accuracy": "0"
  },
  "0": {
    "latitude": 37.33382825,
    "longitude": -122.07735141,
    "accuracy": 5
  },
  "1": {
    "latitude": 37.35304318,
    "longitude": -122.1073468,
    "accuracy": 5
  },
  "2": {
    "latitude": 37.37664016,
    "longitude": -122.14817958,
    "accuracy": 5
  },
  "3": {
    "latitude": 37.38885423,
    "longitude": -122.15958014,
    "accuracy": 5
  },
  "4": {
    "latitude": 37.40479565,
    "longitude": -122.1870328,
    "accuracy": 5
  },
  "5": {
    "latitude": 37.412672,
    "longitude": -122.20550149,
    "accuracy": 5
  }
}
```

As I'm using RN 0.59.1 and React 16.8, I tried:

```
   render() {
     const Test = ({locations}) => (
       <>
         {this.props.locations.map(locations => (
           <Text> key={locations.latitude} {locations.longitude}</Text>
         ))}
       </>
     );

     return (
       <View style={styles.container}>
         <View>
          {Test}
         </View>
       </View>
     );
   }
```

But it doesn't print anything in the view. What am doing wrong?

Edit: I do have Redux configured correctly, because if I console.log(this.props.locations) it'll show me the correct data structure above. So just having trouble mapping to the rendered component.

Comment: does your data is really an object. if that is the case, you can't map it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your data structure into an array,

Like This:

```
    example = [
   {
    "latitude": "0",
    "longitude": "0",
    "accuracy": "0"
  },
  {
    "latitude": 37.33382825,
    "longitude": -122.07735141,
    "accuracy": 5
  },
  {
    "latitude": 37.35304318,
    "longitude": -122.1073468,
    "accuracy": 5
  },
   {
    "latitude": 37.37664016,
    "longitude": -122.14817958,
    "accuracy": 5
  },
  {
    "latitude": 37.38885423,
    "longitude": -122.15958014,
    "accuracy": 5
  },
  {
    "latitude": 37.40479565,
    "longitude": -122.1870328,
    "accuracy": 5
  },
  {
    "latitude": 37.412672,
    "longitude": -122.20550149,
    "accuracy": 5
  }
]
```

Edited 1:

in addition i think one of your mistake is you pass a function inside render. modify your const test just a normal component value

Like this:

```
 render() {
  const Test = (
    <>
      {sample.map(locations => (
        <Text> key={locations.latitude} {locations.longitude}</Text>
      ))}
    </>
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
       {Test}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
}
```

It will work now. Hope it helps :D

Comment: Thank you! After changing my data structure I'm able to access the data.